# sed: replace character at the beginning of a string of n characters

Tags: regex, string, replace, sed, substring

I have:

```
12223335566
19988776655
9918877665566
44410007777222
etc
```

I am trying to find the sed syntax for replacing `1` with nothing only when `1` is at the **beginning** of a string composed of 10 digits so that the above input should look like this:

```
2223335566
9988776655
9918877665566
44410007777222
```

As you can see, the replacement should occur only in the first two strings, leaving the other two untouched because even though the `1` in them is followed by 10 digits, it is not at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove beginning 1 from the 11 digit number :

```
sed 's;^1\([0-9]\{10\}\)$;\1;' filename
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked wonderful. One question: why the `;` instead of the classic `/`? It works like that too.

Comment: `/` Separator is confusing whenever you need to escape string with \ . Therefore I prefer `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed -r 's/^1([0-9]{10})$/\1/' file
```

Comment: Thank you as well, your solution also performs as expected and is a bit cleaner by enabling the `-r` option but Prince John Wesley was a bit faster and I had to give him credit for the solution. Cheers both!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` solution

```
cat file
12223335566
19988776655
1245245543
14545klk342
9918877665566
44410007777222
```

```
awk '$1+0>10000000000 && $1+0<199999999999 {sub(/^1/,x)}8' file
2223335566
9988776655
1245245543
14545klk342
9918877665566
44410007777222
```